# Parsing Integer Value As Datetime

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

I have date represented as integer like `20140820` and I want to parsing it as datetime, like 2014.08.20.

Do I need to parse each integer value (2014)(08)(02) using index or is there simpler way?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) supports `yyyyMMdd` format as a *standard date and time format*, you can just use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) method like;

```
int i = 20140820;
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(i.ToString());
```

If it doesn't support, you need to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.TryParseExact.aspx) methods to parse it as custom date and time format.

```
int i = 20140820;
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(i.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Then you can format your `DateTime` with [`.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string formattedDateTime = dt.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 24):

The easiest and most performance way would be something like:

```
int date = 20140820;

int d = date % 100;
int m = (date / 100) % 100;
int y = date / 10000;

var result = new DateTime(y, m, d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :-

```
string time = "20140820";
DateTime theTime= DateTime.ParseExact(time,
                                    "yyyyMMdd",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

---

OR

```
string str = "20140820";
string[] format = {"yyyyMMdd"};
DateTime date;

DateTime.TryParseExact(str, 
                          format, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
                          out date))
```

now `date` variable will have required `converted date of string '20140820'`

Answer (score 1):

So, we have [two competing implementations](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S0HHeK),

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = 20140820;
        Console.WriteLine($"StringParse:{StringParse.Parse(i)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"MathParse:{MathParse.Parse(i)}");
    }
}

public static class StringParse
{
    public static DateTime Parse(int i)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(
            i.ToString().AsSpan(),
            "yyyyMMdd".AsSpan(),
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}

public static class MathParse
{
    public static DateTime Parse(int i)
    {
        return new DateTime(
                Math.DivRem(Math.DivRem(i, 100, out var day), 100, out var month),
                month,
                day);
    }
}
```

The string approach is probably safer and probably handles edge cases better.
Both will be fast and unlikely to be a performance bottle neck but it is my untested assertion that the math approach probably has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sampleDate = 20140820;
var dateFormat = DateTime.ParseExact(sampleDate.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd",
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
```

result:

***2014.08.20***