# Convert Int to date C#

Tags: c#, datetime, integer, blazor

I feel like this should be pretty easy, but I am having a hard time figuring it out. I am getting a int from an API for a date. The Json provides the date property like this "20210307". What is the best way for me to get this date into into yyyy/mm/dd format and is there a way to also flip things around (maybe put year last?). I have been trying to make a method in the class but only run into problems and it is making me think I am totally off. Thanks!

```
    List<CovidDataModel> coviddata;
    string errorString;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/daily.json");

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            coviddata = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<CovidDataModel>>();
            errorString = null;
        }
        else
        {
            errorString = $"Could not load Covid Data: {response.ReasonPhrase}";
        }
    }
```

---

### PORTION OF MODEL BELOW:

```
public class CovidDataModel
    {
        public int date { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing Integer Value As Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399600/parsing-integer-value-as-datetime)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` to parse custom date formats. Simply switch "yyyyMMdd" accordingly to the int date response you are receiving.

```
int date = 20210307;

var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    date.ToString(), 
    "yyyyMMdd", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

Output:

```
7/3/2021 12:00:00 AM
```

**Edit: Additional Info**

I believe the reasons why you said that "it works when the data is displayed" is because sometimes the request hangs.

- Update your request method as shown in the code below.
- Use nullable types for
  `int` and `DateTime` in `CovidDataModel` Class because some values
  are returned as `null` in the json data and it becomes an issue when
  `deserializing`.

Code with some additional improvements:

```
@page "/"
@using System.Text.Json
@using System.Globalization
@using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
@inject IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Covid Data</h1>

@if (coviddata is null)
{
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-3">
        <p>Loading covid data...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status"></div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" width="50">#</th>
                <th scope="col" width="100">Date</th>
                <th scope="col" width="100">state</th>
                <th scope="col" width="100">positive</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var data in coviddata)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">@(coviddata.IndexOf(data)+1)</th>
                    <td>@ConvertIntToDate(data.date.Value, "yyyyMMdd").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
                    <td>@data.state</td>
                    <td>@data.positive</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
}

@code{
    List<CovidDataModel> coviddata;
    string errorString;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        GetCovidData();
    }

    private async Task GetCovidData()
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault
        };

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

        using (var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/daily.json", 
            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                coviddata = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<CovidDataModel>>(options);
            else
                errorString = $"Could not load Covid Data: {response.ReasonPhrase}";
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private DateTime ConvertIntToDate(int date, string format)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(
            date.ToString(),
            format,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public class CovidDataModel
    {

        public int? date { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public int? positive { get; set; }
        public int? probableCases { get; set; }
        public int? negative { get; set; }
        public object pending { get; set; }
        public string totalTestResultsSource { get; set; }
        public int? totalTestResults { get; set; }
        public int? hospitalizedCurrently { get; set; }
        public int? hospitalizedCumulative { get; set; }
        public int? inIcuCurrently { get; set; }
        public int? inIcuCumulative { get; set; }
        public object onVentilatorCurrently { get; set; }
        public object onVentilatorCumulative { get; set; }
        public int? recovered { get; set; }
        public string lastUpdateEt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateModified { get; set; }
        public string checkTimeEt { get; set; }
        public int? death { get; set; }
        public int? hospitalized { get; set; }
        public object hospitalizedDischarged { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateChecked { get; set; }
        public object totalTestsViral { get; set; }
        public object positiveTestsViral { get; set; }
        public object negativeTestsViral { get; set; }
        public int? positiveCasesViral { get; set; }
        public int? deathConfirmed { get; set; }
        public int? deathProbable { get; set; }
        public int? totalTestEncountersViral { get; set; }
        public int? totalTestsPeopleViral { get; set; }
        public object totalTestsAntibody { get; set; }
        public object positiveTestsAntibody { get; set; }
        public object negativeTestsAntibody { get; set; }
        public object totalTestsPeopleAntibody { get; set; }
        public object positiveTestsPeopleAntibody { get; set; }
        public object negativeTestsPeopleAntibody { get; set; }
        public object totalTestsPeopleAntigen { get; set; }
        public object positiveTestsPeopleAntigen { get; set; }
        public int? totalTestsAntigen { get; set; }
        public object positiveTestsAntigen { get; set; }
        public string fips { get; set; }
        public int? positiveIncrease { get; set; }
        public int? negativeIncrease { get; set; }
        public int? total { get; set; }
        public int? totalTestResultsIncrease { get; set; }
        public int? posNeg { get; set; }
        public object dataQualityGrade { get; set; }
        public int? deathIncrease { get; set; }
        public int? hospitalizedIncrease { get; set; }
        public string hash { get; set; }
        public int? commercialScore { get; set; }
        public int? negativeRegularScore { get; set; }
        public int? negativeScore { get; set; }
        public int? positiveScore { get; set; }
        public int? score { get; set; }
        public string grade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is my answer. I am just struggling to implement it so it works when the data is displayed.

Comment: @NT360 Can you clarify the issue more?

Comment: @NT360 I added additional answer which I believe will solve your struggles with the data.

Comment: THANK YOU! Sorry. I got working on this again and just saw this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your date integer is in yyyymmdd format:

```
int date = 20210307;

int year = date / 10_000;
int month = (date - year * 10_000) / 100; 
int day = date % 100;

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Once you have your `DateTime` you can format it how you like using normal date formatting.

(You can also do it by converting the integer to a string and then parsing it, but obviously that's a lot less efficient - not that that's likely to matter...)

Comment: `int month = date % 10_000 / 100;` is an alternative formula

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to parse the string to an int. If you already receive it as a string you can use DateTime.TryParseExact() to parse it like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myDate = "20220901";
        
        DateTime result;        
        DateTime.TryParseExact(myDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
        
        var newDateFormat = result.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        
        Console.WriteLine(newDateFormat);
    }
}
```

This will give you: "2022/09/01"

You can "flip the things around" by specifying the format string:

```cs
//put year last (Day/Month/Year):
var newDateFormat = result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This will give you: "01/09/2022"

Answer (score 0):

```
int sampleDate = 20210307;
var dateFormat = DateTime.ParseExact(sampleDate.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd",
         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

result:

***"2021/03/07"***